# "TypeError: Client.Collection is not a Constructor" error with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my first time using Discord.js as I'm trying to create a personal music bot for my friend's server. First, I'm going through a tutorial by CodeLyon but I've encountered an error and I'm not sure how to fix it since the video was released before the Gateway Intentions were added to Discord.js

The error I'm currently getting states:

> TypeError: Client.Collection is not a constructor
> at Object.< anonymous> (C:\Users\Jewel Wildmoon\Downloads\My Discord Bots\Music Bots\Bot\main.js:9:19)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

This is my code so far in my main.js file:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Client.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require('./commands/${file}');


    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is Online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command == 'youtube'){
        message.channel.send('LINK');
    }
});


client.login('TOKEN');
```

And this is my current code in the ping.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "This is a ping command",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

Not quite sure what to do here as again, I haven't use Discord.js and am not familiar with Gateway Intentions. That and I'm still new to JavaScript.

Comment: Their client is defined correctly. The error is that `Collection` must be deconstructed from the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection` is exported by the library, its not a client property. You need to deconstruct it at the top along with `Client` and `Intents`.

```js
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');


client.commands = new Collection();
```

Comment: Ah that was why. I deconstructed them at the top but now it's giving me an error stating:
"ReferenceError: Cannot access 'client' before initialization"

And when I place it below the intents, I get:
"Error: Cannot find module './commands/${file}'"

Comment: You shouldn't be moving the position of your imports, it should still be in the name space at top, all you're changing is adding in `Collection`

Comment: Ahh now I understand. Thanks! I also found that the error for the './commands/${file}' ended up being because I used ' ' instead of ` `

Answer (score 0):

The Discord.js `Collection` function isn't a method of the `Client` [[Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object].

Instead it's exported by the **actual module**, instead you should import it from the Discord.js module.

[You can read the Discord.js guide on it here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html).

An example of how this should be used can be seen below.

```js
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');

client.commands = new Collection();
```

In the future, you could read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) on Discord.js or you could read the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help with the constructor. I finally got the bot working (for now) after fixing additional errors with depreciated commands and incorrect characters. The new code I got to work is as follows.

For main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandsFile = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandsFile){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is Online!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', messageCreate => {
    if(!messageCreate.content.startsWith(prefix) || messageCreate.author.bot) return;

    const args = messageCreate.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(messageCreate, args);
    } else if(command === 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(messageCreate, args);
    }
});



client.login('TOKEN');
```

For ping.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "This is a ping command",
    execute(messageCreate, args){
        messageCreate.channel.send('pong!');
    }
```

For youtube.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'youtube',
    description: "Sends a link to a YouTube channel",
    execute(messageCreate, args){
        messageCreate.channel.send('LINK');
    }
}
```